# Howto create a Form Field from a Model in Django?

Tags: django, forms

In a simple form, I have the following classes:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   groupy = models.ForeignKey('Group',null=True)
class Group(models.Model):
  slogan = models.CharField()
```

I now want to create a form which creates an object of both classes simultaneously. My approach so far is:

```
class GroupCreate(CreateView):
  def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(GroupCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['name'] = CharField()
    return form
  def form_valid(self, form):
    response      = super(GroupCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    groupy        = form.save()
    upload        = Upload()
    upload.groupy = groupy
    upload.name   = form.instance.name
    upload.save()
    return response
  ...
```

This works fine. However my problem is, that I have a lot of fields, and I would need to set the options of each field separately. Therefore:

How can I convert the fields of the **Upload** model into **Form** fields and just pipe them into the Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found a solution. If I import `from django.forms.models import modelform_factory`, I can use it to create the fields with:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
  form = super(GroupCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
  upload_form = modelform_factory(Upload,fields=('name',))

  for field in upload_form.base_fields:
    form.fields[field] = upload_form.base_fields[field]
  return form
```

Also the `form_valid` function has to be adapted:

```
  def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    upload.name   = form.cleaned_data['name']
    ...
```